# Where is keywords code assist and letter not allowed problem(Aptana Studio 3)

Tags: aptana, code-assist

I recently switched from Aptana2 to version3.0.3, and the first thing i did was to install the sdomcl. file to get jQuery code assist.It works fine for jQuery, but there is no code assist for many keywords.For exymple there is no support for var,while,throw,try,break,case,catch etc.

Also there is no function, instead intellisense sugests Function.

The second problem is that i am constantly getting this warning '<' + '/' +letter not allowed here when typing something valid like this:

confirmDiv =$("")-sorry for this,but it wont let me type what i want, basically i am just creating a new div with the correct syntax.

Could it be something with Html Tidy?Anyways, big thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Aptana Studio 3.0.4 includes code assist for JavaScript keywords.

Answer (score 0):

I've read that for Javascript the slashes / must be escaped with backslashes \ [as it says here](http://www.htmlpedia.org/wiki/Tidy_32)
Doing so the warning dissapears ;)